# jQuery mobile phonegap flicking and jumping data-role="content" when sliding from page to another

Tags: android, ios, jquery-mobile, phonegap-build

We have using phonegap to build HTML5 application using jQuery mobile for iOS and Android. The problem is when sliding between page and another, the content of data-role='content' is flicking and jumping before fixing in the page. That's is happening on every page without the home screen. In the main page we put the meta view port below:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
```

Thank you for your suggestions...

Answer (score 0):

First off - this is a known issue with jQM. You can turn the transitions off and it'll stop. I've a few apps build with jQM and I, like all people who use jQM and PBG, struggled with this.

Second - don't use jQM. It's not the best thing for this. I recommend Ionic.